# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Creating the web driver failed with the message "End of Central Directory record could not be found."

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, orchardcore

**Full Error:**

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Creating the web driver failed with the message "End of Central Directory record could not be found.". This can mean that there is a leftover web driver process that you have to kill manually.
Full exception: System.IO.InvalidDataException: End of Central Directory record could not be found.
```

I'm running the automatic testing on orchard core solution using Lombiq Test UI. It stops working sometimes and gives this error. I faced same issue on last Friday but after some time it resolved automatically. I was thinking that this is local environment issue but I tried on different systems with same solution but it gives me same error on other systems as well.

Can anyone help me to find out what is the actual issue. Is selenium uses online services for the automation testing which gets down sometime or there is something else.